# Query: Select products from master- and subcategories

Tags: mysql

I need to select products from a master category and all of its subcategories in one query.

I have 3 tables: items, categories, itemCategories (contains links between items and categories). My categories has left and right values ([Wikipedia: Nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)).

My query for a master category with leftCount 5 and rightCount 58:

```
SELECT i.* FROM itemCategories ic, categories c, items i 
WHERE i.isActive = '1' AND i.isHidden = '0' 
AND ic.itemId = i.id AND ic.categoryId = c.id 
AND c.leftCount BETWEEN 5 AND 58
ORDER BY i.sortingValue, i.name
```

I have ~16.000 products and the query above will list approx. 50% of them. To my knowledge this should be af simple operation, but the query takes approx 0.1100 seconds.

Indexes are in place for:

- leftCount in categories
- isActive and isHidden in items
- itemId and categoryId in itemCategories

Do you have any performance suggestions?

**UPDATE**

When I remove the ORDER BY the query time reduces to 0.0007 seconds. So I guess the time is spent sorting a temporary table. Any performance boosters to help this along?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is 110 ms considered slow?

Comment: I'm not certain it's slow, but comparing to my other operations it's definitely much slower. So I was hoping somebody would know of a better method of achieving my goal. The real query also has some left joins, which slows it down a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `BTREE` index on `categories.id` an `categories.leftCount`:

```
ALTER TABLE categories ADD INDEX myIXD USING BTREE (id, leftCount)
```

Comment: Please Show us the whole Picture, I dont want to guess about existing stuff